# Using Team Services online repository without visual studio

Tags: azure-devops, github-desktop

I am trying to use a team services account to store other related documents for a project such as some spreadsheets.  I want the client to have access to it, but they are not programmers so I am not wanting them to use VS.

The client can access it directly without a problem and can download files, the biggest issue is they will need to be able to upload files as well.  Without using a client of some sort they are limited to 10mb or less which won't work for them.

I cannot seem to get github for the desktop to access my online repository unless I first go into VS and clone it.

I am trying to avoid having to walk the client through doing that and would like to be able to use a GUI like github desktop from end to end.

We are all in a Windows environment.

I can create a new repository in github desktop, but cannot seem to figure out how to connect it to my remote (I can't find the URL for the remote anywhere).

I feel I am so close but just missing a couple items, any push would be appreciated.

Comment: Storing binary files in Git is kind of an anti-pattern and it negates the features of Excel and other office products that allow multi-user editing. Tye best place for Office documents is OneDrive or Sharepoint.

Comment: mrHinsh -- you are probably correct.  I will look for a better pattern.  Perhaps just store a link to the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some git GUI or git command line to operate local repo.

**Git GUI:** as Daniel Mann said, you can use soucetree, or tortoiseGit etc.

**Git command line:**

you can download [git here](https://git-scm.com/downloads) ->

`git clone https://account.visualstudio.com/_git/projectname` ->

enter email and password to clone ->

`git add .` (when you add some files)  ->

`git commit -am 'message'`(commit the changes you make) ->

`git push`(push your commits into VSTS git repo) ->

`git pull`(pull VSTS git repo changes to localt).

Answer (score 2):

GitHub Desktop is for GitHub. GitHub is a Git repository hosting service. Not surprisingly, the GitHub tool only works with GitHub.

You can use any general-purpose Git client to interact with VSTS Git repos. SourceTree is good.

Answer (score 0):

I am just closing this out, thank you to both folks who did answer.  I understand that I am using GIT and that GitHub Desktop is for Github.  I was looking for the best way to work with a Github repository without using VS and how to access the team services repo for a client of mine.  I set him up with Gitkraken which is working.  I was never able to figure out how to get Github Desktop to properly clone and push items, but I did not spend a ton of time in it once I used Gitkraken.

Thanks again for taking a swing at it.

I accepted the answer I did because suggesting using the command line at least shows a understanding of my question and what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I know I am late to the game but I can confirm that tortoise git and getext also work fine with VSTS